# Change browserHistory.push('/login') form v2 to alternative in React Router V4

Tags: meteor, react-router-v4

In this tutorial on [Meteor and React](http://www.meteorandreact.com/book/user_system) an author uses react-router v2-3, I want to do it using new React- router v4. So I try to change this code, that used react-router v2:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexLink, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export class Navigation extends React.Component {
    logout(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.logout(function() {
            browserHistory.push('/login');
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
              <div className="container-fluid">
                ...    
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
                  <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Dashboard</IndexLink></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

to this one, that uses v4:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

export class Navigation extends React.Component {
  logout(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    Meteor.logout(function () {
      this.context.history.push('/login')
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <nav className='navbar navbar-default'>
        <div className='container-fluid'>
          ... 
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Dashboard</NavLink></li>
              <li><NavLink to="/logout" activeClassName="active"
                           onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Logout</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

**but** browser console.logs me an error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `/logout` path in your app? I'm asking because you're probably handling that using `logout` method passed into `onClick` prop.

If you look how `<Link>` is working
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.0.0-beta.8/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js
You can see if there is a prop called `onClick` component will call that function with event parameter and if event hasn't set `defaultPrevented` to true `<Link>` will try to go to `/logout` path